# Adding attribute to a Gridview from the code behind

Tags: c#, datatables

Trying to use paging for a datatables, I want to to translate the Dropdown so it says All or Tous in french.  I'm trying to add as an attribute to the Gridview but the quotes are being displayed as &quot which aren't rendering.

i need this
data-wb-tables='{ "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, "All"]], "iDisplayLength": 15, "ordering": true, "order": [ 0, "desc" ], "paging": true, "info": true, "searching": false }'

but I get this

```
data-wb-tables="{ &quot;aLengthMenu&quot;: [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, &quot;All&quot;]], &quot;iDisplayLength&quot;: 15, &quot;ordering&quot;: true, &quot;order&quot;: [ 0, &quot;desc&quot; ], &quot;paging&quot;: true, &quot;info&quot;: true, &quot;searching&quot;: false }" 

 protected void grdAllRequests_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdAllRequests.Attributes.Add("data-wb-tables", grdAllRequestsPagingText());
}

    private string grdAllRequestsPagingText()
{
    //Not implemented yet
    //string localisedText = SiteInfo.IsFrench ? "Tous les" : "All";

    return string.Format("{0}", "'{ \"aLengthMenu\": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, \"All\"]], \"iDisplayLength\": 15, \"ordering\": true, \"order\": [ 0, \"desc\" ], \"paging\": true, \"info\": true, \"searching\": false }'");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    data-wb-tables=@"{""aLengthMenu"": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, ""All""]], ""iDisplayLength"": 15, ""ordering"": true, ""order"": [ 0, ""desc"" ], ""paging"": true, ""info"": true, ""searching"": false }";
protected void grdAllRequests_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdAllRequests.Attributes.Add("data-wb-tables",data-wb-tables);
}
```

Comment: That worked.  I now feel like an even bigger numskull because I can't get my variable to display..         

`string localisedText = SiteInfo.IsFrench ? "Tous les" : "All";
        return @"{""aLengthMenu"": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, ""localisedText""]], ""iDisplayLength"": 15, ""ordering"": true, ""order"": [ 0, ""desc"" ], ""paging"": true, ""info"": true, ""searching"": false }";`

Comment: Where do you want to display?

Comment: I want to replace ""localisedText"" with the contents of the variable localisedText

Comment: Try this..... return string.Format(@"{""aLengthMenu"": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, ""{0}""]], ""iDisplayLength"": 15, ""ordering"": true, ""order"": [ 0, ""desc"" ], ""paging"": true, ""info"": true, ""searching"": false }",localisedText);`

Comment: unfortunately, that gives me 'The input string format is incorrect '

Comment: Try this..... return @"{""aLengthMenu"": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, """ + localisedText + @"""]], ""iDisplayLength"": 15, ""ordering"": true, ""order"": [ 0, ""desc"" ], ""paging"": true, ""info"": true, ""searching"": false }";`

Comment: That finally did the job!  Thx, had been wrestling with this since early this AM!!!!